# Как правильно реализовать задачу со стрингом java?

Tags: java, строки

Есть такая задача : [image: Задача]

Я написал такой код:

```
public class ClassRepeat {
    public static String repeat(String word, int n) {
        String[] arr = new String[word.length() * n];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = word.substring(i).repeat(n);
        }
        String result = new String(String.valueOf(arr));
        return result;
    }
```

И оно не показывает нужный мне результат,всегда у меня проблемы с этими стрингами)

Comment: "всегда у меня проблемы с этими стрингами"........."оно не показывает нужный мне результат" --- по-моему это полностью неинформативное описание проблемы

Answer (score 1):

```
 static void repeat(String word, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < times; j++) {

                System.out.print(word.charAt(i));

            }
        }
    }
```